# Problem installing omni compiler - fatal error: mpi.h: No such file or directory

Tags: macos, terminal, openmpi

I am trying to install omni compiler in order to compile XcalableMP programs on OSX. I can `./configure` successfully as per the instructions but am receiving this error when I `make`:

`../include/xmp_internal.h:19:10: fatal error: mpi.h: No such file or directory`

My Open MPI is installed via homebrew and mpi.h is located through my Cellar folder. How do I go about including this header file?

Answer (score 2):

can you try the following command to be sure the location of the installed openmpi is correct:

```
mpicc -showme
```

Then, are you sure the mpi path is in your path, try to set these environment variables and then try:

Note that I assume the openmpi is installed in "/home/openmpi" path for example:

```
export PATH=/home/opempi/bin:/home/opempi/include:$PATH
```

and for the runtime:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/openmpi/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Then try to configure and make again the omnicomppiler,